# My ipod is stolen, will i be able to retain progress on games

Tags: ios, ipod, iphone, games

My ipod 5 got stolen and I was wondering if, when I get a new device (iPhone 5s) will I be able to keep my progress on the games on my ipod that I have through game centre. I'm hoping that when I get the new device, I'll log into gamecentre then install the apps and games I had on my ipod and have them up to speed with where they were on the ipod, mainly because I had progressed very far in the game 'clash of clans'. Is this possible?

Comment: Save data will restore only if you have a backup that you restored from. It can be either iTunes or iCloud backup.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the game.

Some games store data on the phone that is only recoverable from your backup, if you have one.

Other games/apps store data on the developer's servers and will be available when you sign back into the game or Game Center on your device.

For the Game "**Clash of Clans**" the save progress is matched with your Game Centre account.